# Sending multiline string into listViewAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have the following method in my class:

```
private String getCallDetails()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null,null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String callDirection = null;
        int callDirectionCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (callDirectionCode)
        {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                callDirection = "OUTGOING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                callDirection = "INCOMING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                callDirection = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
        sb.append(callDirection+"||"+phNumber+"||"+callDuration+"||"+callDayTime+";\n");
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

which returns the following output:

```
2018-09-12 17:43:55.253 6883-6883/test.package.android D/callDetails: OUTGOING||17||9||Tue Aug 28 11:09:21 GMT+02:00 2018;
OUTGOING||17||0||Fri Aug 31 15:03:34 GMT+02:00 2018;
INCOMING||17||13||Fri Aug 31 15:17:00 GMT+02:00 2018;
```

What I want to do is separate each line and in each line separate items divided with "||" and set them as strings that I can use. How can I do this

Comment: You could split the result of this method with regex "||"

Comment: @jrsall92 I already did that. But I don't know how to repeat that for every line printed and send it to helper class which will populate ListView items. I'm still beginneer in Java, so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: So you may have multiple lines in the same string? If that's the case then add "\n" to the end of the string and then first split at "\n" and then split each element of the resulting array at "||"

Comment: @jrsall92 Thanks for the suggestion. Managed to do that with regex.